# How to backup the Google App Engine Full Text Search documents?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, full-text-search, google-cloud-datastore, gae-search

First of all, thank you Google for full text search support.

How do I backup the Documents that I have stored in the full text search datastore?

Can I use `appcfg.py download_data`?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use download_data to backup full text search stored indexes.

They are like datastores functionally and they are stored similar. If you want to "backup" the data, you can programmatically fetch them and copy them into another search index and then save it. Or simply pull it out and save it to Cloud Storage or something similar.

In summary, there is no one command solution for backing up Full Text Search Index data; you must write code to fetch, write and save them somewhere.